# App shows a different activity layout when launched for the first time

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-cardview

I'm sorry for the confusion for the title but this is what happens

[image]
This is what the app looks like and it works fine.

HOWEVER...
When the app is launched everytime it shows this.

[image]

For some weird reason the card view stretches. This only happens everytime you open the app. It goes back to normal when you tap on assessment then go back.

I don't know what to do because my xml codes is all working as intended on the first photo and I don't know what causes this problem.

CODE:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:text=" "
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:fontFamily="@font/ness"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_view2"
    android:layout_width="294dp"
    android:layout_height="58dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title_view"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="65dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="52dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="112dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/ness"
    android:text="What do you want to do today?"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/title_view"
    android:layout_margin="100dp"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="3">


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/assess_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/asses" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Assessment"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>




    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/profile_menu"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/profile" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Profile"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>







</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need grid layout in this ui? And your android:columnCount="2" and android:rowCount="3" it's can be reason. Maybe you should use constraintlayout.

UPDATED

Try code below, maybe it can solve your problem.
Also I have seen you used RelativeLayout, for now day it's deprecated and google recommend to use constraintlayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_view2"
        android:layout_width="294dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/ness"
        android:text="What do you want to do today?"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/assess_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/title_view2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/title_view2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_view2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/asses" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Assessment"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/profile_menu"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/assess_menu"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/assess_menu"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/assess_menu">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/profile" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Profile"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```